# imshow inverts colors after using astype(float)

Tags: matplotlib

I'm using matplotlib `imshow` to visualize data from cifar-10. After reading in cifar10 data I've noticed that the image rendered from `imshow` is different after I use `.astype(float)`.

For example,

Without `.astype(float)`

[image]

Here's what I see with `.astype(float)`

[image]

Why does it look like the image is rendering with the colors inverted?

Here is the code I am using:

```
dir = 'resources/datasets/cifar-10-batches-py'
import cPickle
fo = open(dir + '/data_batch_1', 'rb')
dict = cPickle.load(fo)
fo.close()
X=dict['data'].reshape((10000, 3, 32, 32)).transpose(0, 2, 3, 1).astype(float)
Y=dict['labels']
plt.imshow(X[2,])
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

A little late but for people seeking help and finding this post:

A good explanation of how matplotlib decides on the colormap is given in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24739769/matplotlib-imshow-plots-different-if-using-colormap-or-rgb-array).

I have just faced this same problem and found a solution in this post. It seems that matplotlib assumes 3d images of type float to be in range [0,1] and uses a modulo operation with 1 to clamp the values like 2.7 -> 0.7.

Try this:

```
X=dict['data'].reshape((10000, 3, 32, 32)).transpose(0, 2, 3,1)

X = X.astype(float) / 255    
plt.imshow(X[2,])
```

Now matplotlib should directly use the values provided and not use internal modulo magic.