# Why doesn't an array made from a PIL draw.text() image show properly in Matplotlib?

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, python-imaging-library

I'd like to *understand why*, when I convert the PIL image `imageRGB` to a float array `arrayRGB_f` and use matplotlib's `imshow()` without a cmap it looks either black, or strange and unreadable, even though PIL's `imageRGB.show()` looks fine, and each of the individual r, g, b channels shown with `cmap='gray'` look okay as well.

I have workarounds, but I just don't understand why this happens.

`matplotlib.__version__` returns `'2.0.2'` and I'm using MacOS with an Anaconda installation.

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47546095/3904031) for more on the conversion of a ttf rendering to a 1bit.

fyi the output of the print statements are:

```
float64 (41, 101, 3)
int64 (41, 101, 3)
int64 (41, 101)
int64 (41, 101)
```

---

```
fontname   = 'default'
```

`imageRGB.show()`

[image]

`plt.imshow()`

[image]

```
fontname   = 'Arial Unicode.ttf'
```

`imageRGB.show()`

[image]

`plt.imshow()`

[image]

```
font   = ImageFont.truetype(fontname, 20)
```

`imageRGB.show()`

[image]

`plt.imshow()`

[image]

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# fontname   = 'Arial Unicode.ttf' 
fontname   = 'default' 

if fontname == 'default':
    font   = ImageFont.load_default()
else:
    font   = ImageFont.truetype(fontname, 12)

string     = "Hello " + fontname[:6]
ww, hh     = 101, 41
threshold  = 80   # https://stackoverflow.com/a/47546095/3904031

imageRGB   = Image.new('RGB', (ww, hh))
draw       = ImageDraw.Draw(imageRGB)
image8bit  = draw.text((10, 12), string, font=font,
                       fill=(255, 255, 255, 255))  # R, G, B alpha

image8bit  = imageRGB.convert("L")
image1bit  = image8bit.point(lambda x: 0 if x < threshold else 1, mode='1')  # https://stackoverflow.com/a/47546095/3904031

arrayRGB   = np.array(list(imageRGB.getdata())).reshape(hh, ww, 3)
arrayRGB_f = arrayRGB.astype(float)

array8bit  = np.array(list(image8bit.getdata())).reshape(hh, ww)
array1bit  = np.array(list(image1bit.getdata())).reshape(hh, ww)

for a in (arrayRGB_f, arrayRGB, array8bit, array1bit):
    print a.dtype, a.shape

imageRGB.show()

if True:
    plt.figure()

    a = arrayRGB_f
    plt.subplot(2, 2, 1)
    plt.imshow(a)  # , interpolation='nearest',  cmap='gray',

    for i in range(3):
        plt.subplot(2, 2, 2+i)
        plt.imshow(a[:, :, i], cmap='gray') 

    plt.suptitle('arrayRGB_f, fontname = ' + fontname)
    plt.show()
```

Comment: Use `a = arrayRGB_f/255.` because float arrays should be in the range between 0. and 1.

Comment: [This is the output I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YzrcV.png) using the proposed solution. Do you get the exact same output when trying a = arrayRGB_f/255.? (Note that I'm talking about images here, which are 3D rgb arrays, unnormalized 2D data arrays work fine of course)

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Oh geez, that's right! When it's an `n x m x 3` Matplotlib does *expect* normalized values. I'm usually looking at rainbow plots of `n x m`. Consider posting an answer? I will later if nobody does. Looks great here!

Comment: Nah, this question has been asked a hundred times already. You may find the appropriate duplicate and close it as such if you want.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest It's `05:40 AM` here, I may just delete and go to sleep.

Comment: I wouldn't delete it. Apparently the wording you used made not find you any answer, so keeping this question linking to a duplicate for a proper solution might be helpful for other people in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't find an ideal duplicate so I'll post an answer.

As @ImportanceOfBeingErnest [mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51755124/why-doesnt-an-array-made-from-a-pil-draw-text-image-show-properly-in-matplotl?noredirect=1#comment90470915_51755124) when `.imshow()` is given an `n x m x 3` or `n x m x 4` array, it is expecting a normalized array between 0.0 and 1.0.

Best way to do this is:

```
arrayRGB_f = arrayRGB.astype(float)/255.
```

though this seems to work as well:

```
arrayRGB_f = arrayRGB.astype(float)
arrayRGB_f = arrayRGB_f / arrayRGB_f.max()
```

For longer discussions, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24739769/3904031) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42044259/3904031).

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest how does this look (I couldn't find a good dupe)

Comment: What about [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24739769/matplotlib-imshow-plots-different-if-using-colormap-or-rgb-array)?

Comment: Or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42044259/getting-black-plots-with-plt-imshow-after-multiplying-image-array-by-a-scalar)?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest in this case, this answer is actually the best, it literally "solved my problem" so I'm going to leave it here. Both of those have answers that do contain the solution, but it takes a while to find it as they contain a lot more information to read through. This is exactly what I needed to see, and your comments now direct people to deeper explanations. I'll add those back into the answer as well. Thank you very much for your time and help!